# Hold on until module updates VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-project

I have a module that creates a custom tab in MS Project. This module is updated in another computer and when there's a new version the module is removed and imported again. I do this by running a code that checks for updates on `Project_Activate` and also calls the module where the custom tab is coded.
The problem is when there's an update, the call for the module on `Project_Activate`does not work because the module was removed.

This is what I am using on `Project_Activate`:

```
Set rng_modules = xlbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A3")  'Column with modules names
Do While rng_modules.Value <> Empty
    'Updated modules if necessary
    linha = rng_modules.Row
    Set atualizado = username.Offset(linha - 2)
    Set module_name = rng_modules.Offset(, 1)
    If atualizado.Value = "Not Updated" Then
        With ThisProject.VBProject
            len1 = Len(module_name.Value)
            len2 = len1 - 4
            module_name_short = Left(module_name.Value, len2)
            On Error Resume Next
            .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents(module_name_short)
            .VBComponents.import modulesVBA_loc & module_name.Value
        End With
        atualizado.Value = "Updated"
    End If
    Set rng_modules = rng_modules.Offset(1)
Loop 

PNtab 'Sub in module PNtab_mod that has the custom tab coded in XML
```

Comment: So what is the piece of code that is not working?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention the name of the Sub. I've edited the code above. I wish to call `PNtab` sub

Comment: You can use : Application.Run "PNTab"